# Uploading Node.js app to WinSCP server

Tags: node.js, deployment, winscp

I failed to make my node app work in WinSCP. To my understanding, node version 6 is installed on the server, while my node version is at at 8+. Does it matter? I also got e.g. express, mongoose and handlebars in my app. Do I need to add those in the server as well?

What are the proper steps to upload a node app?

Comment: There's nothing like "WinSCP server".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server, you should have node install the app. This way node will download and install the files/libraries that are required in your package.json file on the server.
try this.
Upload your project to the server and change to the directory of your project. if node_modules exists delete the folder then run.

```
npm install
```

This should create a node_module folder and install all the requirements.
Once the install is complete you should be able to run your app with.

```
npm start
```